# best approach towards animation in Swift xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an animation that I want to do, something very similar to this one

> something similar to the css animated arrows

https://codepen.io/kscboston/full/wYEWYj

my approach (for now)
is to have one of this white arrows in an SVG file
and then have a UI View in my storyboard
and in the UI VIEW class
to do an animations using

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
    self.do something with svf
})
```

and then somehow in the class do the animation using the gifs' and the svf file?

do you know of the best approach to ado what I want?
or what would you suggest for me to do to achieve the CSS animated arrows on Xcode using Swift 4.0?

Comment: Go through these posts ,1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/1746-how-to-create-a-complex-loading-animation-in-swift and 2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationgroup

Comment: You can use [Apple `Core Animation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore) to do anything, but now a days I've been using this animation tool from Airbnb: https://airbnb.design/lottie/ Here you can find the github: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios Community with a lot of elements: https://www.lottiefiles.com I fell in love with this tool and I hope this can introduce a really good tool for someone else.